# Long package name build error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

The package name of my app is very long:

```
app.running.com.voice.and.service.song.backup.audio.run.inthe.background
```

This is a B2B project and I can't reduce their package name now as it is already fixed.

> ```
> Error:failed writing to 'D:\Google_Play\Android Studio\IndWork\Sound\Sound\app\build\generated\source\r\androidTest\debug\app\running\com\voice\and\service\song\backup\audio\run\inthe\background\test\R.java':
> ```
>
> The system cannot find the file specified. (2).

I think there has to be a solution for this problem. Pls guide.

Comment: What makes you think the error is caused by the package name length?

Comment: Because that error has the full path as per the package name, I mean folders as per package names.

Comment: Yes but the error message doesn't state that the path is too long, just that it cannot find it.

Comment: When I reduce the length of the package name then Build is successful

Comment: Well, your could move the project outside of `Google_Play\Android Studio`. Or build it in Linux, where there is less of a restriction on path length

Comment: If you are using windows 10 and have updated with the anniversary update, then You could follow this instructions to enable long file path which might fix ur issue. https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/

Comment: @IsmailIqbal  your answer is correct, pls add it as answer so that I can award bounty to you

Comment: @sandeep happy that it helped you. I have added it as the answer :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **Windows 10** as the OS and have install the **anniversary update** ([Use this link by tuneComp](https://tunecomp.net/how-to-check-if-the-windows-10-anniversary-update-is-installed-or-not/)  to verify if you have installed the anniversary update), then you could follow [this instructions by howToGeek](http://howtogeek.com/266621/) to enable long file path which should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

package name don't have anything wrong with it as far as i know 

as log say's error is at `\build\generated` my first suggestion is to clean project with command

```
$ gradlew clean
```

at root of your project if it's unable to clean delete manually

- android/build
- android/app/build

don't worry the are generated files .
then type  in root of project

```
$ gradlew build
```

be sure your connected to internet to get needed lib from maven or etc.