# Android resource linking failed error: failed writing to The data is invalid. (13)

Tags: java, android, build

All my Drawables are good, They don't have any kind of errors, same as my XML files.
I have tried to invalidate the cache and rebuild
Please help
I have also inspected my code but there are no errors

```
     Android resource linking failed
     Output:  error: failed writing to 'C:\Users\DEV\Desktop\players - 
     Copy\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt': The data is invalid. (13).

     Command: C:\Users\DEV\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971- 
    windows.jar\cb53942e601dc602d2c24f120b0cc26a\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
    C:\Users\DEV\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar\
    --manifest\
    C:\Users\DEV\Desktop\players - 
  
  
    Copy\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
    -o\
    C:\Users\DEV\Desktop\players - 
    Copy\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
    -R\
    @C:\Users\DEV\Desktop\players - Copy\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
    --auto-add-overlay\
    --java\
    C:\Users\DEV\Desktop\players - Copy\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
    --proguard-main-dex\
    C:\Users\DEV\Desktop\players - Copy\app\build\intermediates\legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules\debug\processDebugResources\manifest_keep.txt\
    --custom-package\
    umo.com.players\
    -0\
    apk\
    --output-text-symbols\
    C:\Users\DEV\Desktop\players - Copy\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
    --no-version-vectors
 Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to the following settings in build.gradle file :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

source [R.txt': The data is invalid. (13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54588916/r-txt-the-data-is-invalid-13)