# Android studio AAPT: error failed writing to R.txt: the data is invalid

Tags: android-studio, gradlew, aapt2

I am having an issue with building new projects on android studio. I keep on getting the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     AAPT: error: failed writing to 'D:\Libraries\Documents\AndroidStudio\SocketTest\app\build\intermediates\runtime_symbol_list\debug\R.txt': The data is invalid. (13).
```

Here is my project build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sockettest"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

This problem only occurs on new projects I try to build and isn't an issue on older ones. 
I have read through [R.txt': The data is invalid. (13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54588916/r-txt-the-data-is-invalid-13) which leads to [Long package name build error in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48975350/long-package-name-build-error-in-android-studio) which still does not solve the problem.

I only encounter this issue while using windows 10 (update 1909), and not while using android studio on ubuntu. I am running android studio version 3.6.2

Comment: check your antivirus, that was my case :)

Answer (score 30):

I know this is a year late but could it be an antivirus blocking it? This is what Avast came up with:

[image]

Comment: Yes sir, just avast is blocking me, and I dont see it beacause it was in silence mode, thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

In case someone new to android studios like me does not know how to downgrade Gradle and plugin, here's how (windows):

1. Select File>Project Structure.
2. Type in (3.6.3) the Android Gradle Plugin Version.
3. Type/select (6.0) from dropdown menu the Gradle Version.
4. Hit `OK` to `Save`.

Android Studios will download and set up the new Gradle for the current project. This resolved the `data is invalid` error for me.

Comment: Ah good call, should have included instructions myself.

Comment: Try android plugin version 4.0.1  and gradle version 6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Was getting the same error. I realized it had something to do with the Gradle version I was running, even though I usually stick to the stable channel of releases. I ended up downgrading to plugin version: 3.6.3 & Gradle version 6.0. I had previously been on plugin version 4.0.0 & Gradle version 6.1.1.

I don't know if this was for sure the same issue, this was happening to any projects on my Win10 PC (ver 2004) that were running that Gradle version.

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow this :**

Uninstall your System(Windows OS)anti virus and most probably it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I already solved by adding this in my dependency

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to build an ionic capacitor app with android studio. I later discovered that one of the directories' names in the project's path has space in the name.
I just copied the project into another directory to form a path that has no space and recompiled the project and the error vernished.