# Unknown error in android studio.(resources)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, android-resources

I have been working on an app recently. It worked fine on the first but after some time the build started to fail with mentioning this in the log

```
AAPT: error: failed writing to 'C:\Users\Dr.Nickson\Desktop\GitHub\FutureFurnitureUI-Android\app\build\intermediates\runtime_symbol_list\debug\R.txt': The data is invalid. (13).
```

As i think it should be an error in the resources but I don't know or I might be wrong.
The red squigly lines are shown under the "app" directory.

I also looked up for the R.txt.data is inavlid(13) solution and updated plugins and gradle version and i think it became worse.
Heres my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shashank.platform.furnitureecommerceappui"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


}
```

Here is the gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
#Mon Nov 09 06:54:21 IST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

The only help the IDE gives is the squigly red lines under the app directory as I see it.
Any help would be really appreciated as I've been stuck in this for 2 weeks.

Comment: this post might be help https://stackoverflow.com/a/62919369/10778405

Comment: I read that as well but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, turns out my avg antivirus was blocking the build of the app for some reason. Check your antivirus and give the permission to allow the build of the app.